# Autofit rows using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do AutoFit cells in the range A2 to AA2.

Below is the code I am trying:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wkSt As String
Dim wkBk As Worksheet
wkSt = ActiveSheet.Name
For Each wkBk In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    wkBk.Activate
    Cells.Range("A2:AA2").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Next wkBk
Sheets(wkSt).Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Below is some sample Excel data, as displayed on the screen:

```
     A            B           C
1    Jhon is the best employee
2    Emp_Name     Emp_id      Empsal.
```

Note that "Jhon is the best employee" is all in one cell (A1) but when displayed its contents overlap cells B1 and C1.

With the above code, the data is then displayed as follows:

```
     A                               B       C
1    Jhon is the best employee
2    Emp_Name                        Emp_id  Empsal
```

How can I do AutoFit on each cell of the second row in each worksheet? Above code failing to autofit data from my second row.

This is what I want the display to look like:

```
     A        B      C
1    Jhon is the best employee
2    Emp_Name Emp_id Empsal.
```

i.e. the columns should fit snuggly around "Emp_Name", "Emp_id" and "Empsal." -- not around "Jhon is the best employee".

**EDIT** Also, if there are data in the following rows (3, 4, etc.) then these should be included in the Autofit as well. For example, data should display like below:

```
     A          B      C
1    Jhon is the best employee
2    Emp_Name   Emp_id Empsal.
3    Jhon Peter 2      2000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you want is to force Autofit to ignore the first row and only Autofit based on the content of rows 2 and greater. I don't think this is possible.
One way to do it would be to store the content of the first row, delete it, autofit and insert the content of the first row back:

```
Public Sub test()

  Dim wkSt As String
  Dim wkBk As Worksheet
  Dim temp As Variant

  wkSt = ActiveSheet.Name
  For Each wkBk In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      On Error Resume Next
      wkBk.Activate
      temp = wkBk.Rows(1)
      wkBk.Rows(1).ClearContents
      wkBk.Columns("A:AA").AutoFit
      wkBk.Rows(1) = temp
  Next wkBk
  Sheets(wkSt).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing Autofit on `EntireColumn`, do it on `Columns`.

```
wkBk.Range("A2:AA2").Columns.AutoFit
```

Have a look at VBA help for AutoFit...

**EDIT** You now want to do AutoFit not only for row 2, but also 3, 4, 5 etc. This requires only a simple modification:

```
wkBk.Range("A2:AA999").Columns.AutoFit
```

The above assumes that row 999 is your last row with data to be autofitted. You can also include all rows all the way down to the bottom of the sheet like this:

```
wkBk.Range(Range("A2"), Cells(wkBk.Rows.Count, "AA")).Columns.AutoFit
```

This should be enough to get you on the right track.

Comment: It is doing for only columns,not for rows 3 rd,4th,5th etc. i wanted to do this for each cell from the row second.

Comment: Well, you didn't mention this in your original question. I have now edited my answer to address this.